# HAPI reply is being sent prior to the handler on subsequent calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

Building my first HAPI api back-end, and ran into something odd.  When I hit an endpoint the first time (GET /api/item/{name}, I can see in my console that the handler functions are being run (mongo queries), and then the reply is sent (there's an on response plug-in logging those).  Great.  If I hit the endpoint again with a different parameter, I see the response from the first call going out right away, and then the handler functions are hit.  And, in fact, the client is getting the same response as from the first call.

And I'm not even sure what would be most helpful to post up here.

Here's most of the entry point js (missing config for environment and winston):

```
const Hapi = require('hapi');
server = new Hapi.Server();

var mongo_connect = 'mongodb://' + options.mongo_creds + options.mongo_host + ':' + options.mongo_port + '/' + options.mongo_db;
const dbOpts = {
    url: mongo_connect,
    settings: {
        poolSize: options.mongo_pool
    },
    decorate: true
};

server.connection({ port: options.server_port });

var routes = require('./routes');

if (options.env === "dev") {
    server.on('response', function (request) {
        winston.log('verbose', `[launch_api] ${request.info.remoteAddress}: ${request.method.toUpperCase()} ${request.url.path} --> ${request.response.statusCode}`);
    });
}

server.register({
    register: require('hapi-mongodb'),
    options: dbOpts
}, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        winston.log('error', "[launch_api] Unable to register db pool");
        throw err;
    }

    server.route(routes);

    server.start(function(err) {

        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        winston.log('info', `[launch_api] Server running at: ${server.info.port}`);
    });
});
```

Routes are pulled together in an index.js in the routes folder, but each file there looks something like:

```
'use strict';
var controller = require('../controllers/item-controller')

// Routes for Item

module.exports = [
    {
        method: 'POST',
        path: '/api/item',
        config: controller.create
    },
    {
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/api/items',
        config: controller.fetchAll
    },
    {
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/api/item/{name}',
        config: controller.find
    }
];
```

The controllers all look something like this (just showing the find function for brevity, since this is already long)

```
const Boom = require('boom');
const Joi = require('joi');
const Item = require('../models/item');

module.exports = {
    find: {
        handler: function(request, reply) {
            Item.initFromName(request.params.name).then( function(newItem) {
                if (newItem == null) {
                    reply(Boom.notFound());
                }
                else {
                    reply(newItem);
                }
            }, function(err) {
                reply(Boom.badImplementation());
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly, the models tend to follow this, er, model (again, cutting out all the prototype extensions, and just keeping the one class function in this route)

```
const deferred = require('deferred')()
const winston = require('winston');

const collection_name = "items";


var Item = function() {
    this.name = "";
    this.description = "";
};

// private

function fillFromDB(obj, record) {
    obj._id = record._id;
    obj.name = record.name;
    obj.description = record.description;
}

// Constructor
module.exports.init = function() {
    return new Item();
};

module.exports.initFromName = function(name) {
    var item = new Item();
    const db = server.mongo.db;
    db.collection(collection_name).findOne({name: name}).then( function(opResult) {
            winston.log("debug","Item.loadFromName opResult is: " + opResult);
        if (opResult != undefined) {
            winston.log("debug","Item.loadFromName opResult json is: " + JSON.stringify(opResult));
            fillFromDB(item, opResult);
            deferred.resolve(item);
        } 
        else {
            winston.log("debug","Resolving with null" );
            deferred.resolve();
        }
    }, function(err) {
        winston.log("error", "Item.loadFromName mongo error: " + err);
        deferred.reject();
    });
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

so with all that, if I hit my endpoint with curl with a name that is *not* present in the collection, I get a 404 as expected.  If I then hit with a name that is, I still get the 404.

This input:

```
$ curl -X GET http://192.168.99.100:3000/api/item/not_here
{"statusCode":404,"error":"Not Found"}
$ curl -X GET http://192.168.99.100:3000/api/item/here
{"statusCode":404,"error":"Not Found"}
```

produces this log:

```
debug: Item.loadFromName opResult is: null
debug: Resolving with null
verbose: [launch_api] 192.168.99.1: GET /api/item/not_here --> 404
verbose: [launch_api] 192.168.99.1: GET /api/item/here --> 404
debug: Item.loadFromName opResult is: [object Object]
debug: Item.loadFromName opResult json is: {"_id":"58b622908ea4d1cee2f46462","name":"here","description":"this item is here"}
```

Note that the opposite direction works, too.  If I stop and start node, and then hit the endpoint with the name that is present, all subsequent calls will get that same object returned.  I just can't figure out where this caching is happening.

Comment: To summarise your question, hapi appears to be caching the response?

Comment: Yeah, I should have just said that, eh?  tl;dr :)  But I haven't done anything that I can see to enable caching, and I thought I saw in one of the catbox tuts I was scanning through that it had to be explicitly enabled.

Comment: Where does item variable come from in initFromName  function?  That maybe causing issue, also what is deffered library? Promises need to wrapped properly when using the reply interface.

Comment: ah, bad edit during sanitization, sorry, that's the first line in the func, will edit.

Comment: Deferred is the straight npm deferred lib.  Not sure what you mean by "promises need to be wrapped properly" - all promises should be resolved or rejected before building the reply here.  i.e. replies are only done in the controller, and any promises are in the model or below.

Comment: You're on the right track, though.  I redid the model to just do a straight return with the given name and plugging the current date into the description, no promises, and it works as expected.

Comment: Why don't you construct item model from the record found from database, object mutation is causing your issues here.  I would check promise examples with hapi handlers so you can get syntax right.  I only use callbacks and don't know promises very well.

Comment: Found it - the problem was the global instantiation of the deferred object.  Moved that into a local const in the function and all is well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the global instantiation of the deferred object.  Not sure where I saw that, but it's a bad idea.

In the model, change the first line to just the require

```
const deferred = require('deferred');
```

Then, in the function create your deferred object there.

```
module.exports.initFromName = function(name) {
    const defer = deferred();
    var item = new Item();
    const db = server.mongo.db;
    db.collection(collection_name).findOne({name: name}).then( function(opResult) {
            winston.log("debug","Item.loadFromName opResult is: " + opResult);
        if (opResult != undefined) {
            winston.log("debug","Item.loadFromName opResult json is: " + JSON.stringify(opResult));
            fillFromDB(item, opResult);
            defer.resolve(item);
        } 
        else {
            winston.log("debug","Resolving with null" );
            defer.resolve();
        }
    }, function(err) {
        winston.log("error", "Item.loadFromName mongo error: " + err);
        defer.reject();
    });
    return defer.promise;
};
```